# Edge Cases regarding Continuity and Differentiability

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

I have come across many questions asking to check the continuity and differentiability of functions, and have gotten stuck on a good number of them, whenever some edge case crops up. I also understand that a few of these doubts stem from the fact that there are multiple definitions, but I do not know which definition is more standard and accepted. To summarize, these are my doubts.

1. For a differentiable function defined on a closed interval, say [a,b], is it differentiable at the endpoints? I know that it's RIGHT differentiable at x=a, and LEFT differentiable at x=b, but without the "right" or "left" specification, if a question just asks about the differentiability, would the answer be yes or no?
2. For a point discontinuity, such as that at x=0 in the signum function, is the derivative defined? And if it is defined, and if we approach the function from, say, the right, would the RHD be zero or negative infinity? (Zero, since if we differentiate a constant function, the derivative is zero, and - infinity, from first principles)
3. If the slope of a function is infinity at some point, would we say that the derivative EXISTS and is infinity, or would we say that the derivative is not defined?

Just for some context, I am a high school student preparing for JEE Advanced. Any push towards the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Let me suggest that you ask one focussed question at a time, otherwise you are at high risk of your question being closed for lack of focus. So for starters, pick which one of 1, 2, 3 you most care about and focus your question on that.

Comment: Many of your questions will have varying answers depending on author conventions, including the issue of infinite derivatives (although outside of fairly specialized/advanced work, "differentiable" almost always means "finitely differentiable"; and usually "finitely or infinitely differentiable" deals with the extended real line, that is, derivatives must exist as a real number or as $+\infty$ or as $-\infty).$ Since you are interested in the JEE Advanced test, you need to ask someone familiar with that specific test.

Comment: @LeeMosher Apologies, will take care of that in the future. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you. Is one convention more accepted than the other, though? Cause i did check with my teachers and friends, and I'm getting varying responses. Moreover, the definition used does not seem to be consistent among all the questions I've solved so far.

Comment: Usually differentiability on $[a,b]$ means right-differentiable at $x=a$ and left-differentiable at $x=b,$ with only finite derivatives being used. At a point of discontinuity (where the function is also defined), not being continuous implies not being (two-sided) finitely differentiable. However, at points of discontinuity the function can have one or both one-sided finite derivatives; the function can have one or both infinite two-sided (or one-sided) derivatives; the function can have neither a left nor a right finite or infinite derivative. But I would especially **(continued)**

Comment: recommend that you to look for authoritative guides for how the JEE test handles infinite derivatives (if at all). For example, the function defined by $f(1/n) = n$ for $n$ an odd integer and $f(1/n) = -n$ for $n$ a nonzero even integer and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise has neither a left nor a right *signed* infinite derivative at $x=0,$ but it does have what is sometimes called an *unsigned* infinite derivative at $x=0$ (meaning that the absolute value of the function has an infinite derivative, necessarily positive but usually the sign would be left off). By an "authoritative guide" **(continued)**

Comment: I'm excluding random internet practice JEE problems (unless at their official web site) or even published test prep materials, unless they are actual past questions and the explanations are "official explanations" by the makers/writers of the test itself. *CORRECTION* The example I gave in my last comment is not correct, because the function keeps going back down to $0.$ It needs to be changed so that the function has only the values $-n$ and $n$ for even and odd values of $n$ (in intervals $(\frac{1}{n+1},\,\frac{1}{n}],$ or some such method).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Understood, thank you so much. I shall also, as you recommended, try to look for what the JEE Advanced accepts as the definition, perhaps from questions asked in the previous years, and their official solutions.